# Preventing FF4's new drag feature

Tags: css, firefox4

Is there a way to prevent this in Firefox 4.0 using CSS? It's where you click on a link (or anything) and begin to drag it, and another semi-transparent image of it appears under your cursor as you drag...

Looks something like this:

[image]

Comment: You'll probably need to do something with javascript.

Comment: I use the drag feature all the time to drop a link on the window and/or tab where I want it opened. I wouldn't like it to be disabled.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but it's only a few links that bother me... and I doubt they'd be dragged anyway!

Comment: Why though? Every site *not* restricting drags has this. It's not like users go around dragging every element and blame you. IMO, it's something that shouldn't be bothered with.

Comment: It's not specific to FF4. I'm pretty sure that all browsers do this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Draggable link:

```
<a href="#">Link</a>
```

Non-draggable link:

```
<a href="#" draggable="false">Link</a>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/Xy4vJ/).

Comment: Love it when it's easy. Just to reiterate some of the comments on the question, you probably shouldn't use this just because the browser functionality "bothers you".

Comment: @BryanDowning Absolutely, however it does make sense for links, like this example, which don't actually go anywhere (though, of course, that's not a great example of best practice either ;) )

Answer (score 4):

I have not found a CSS solution yet (I will keep looking), but in the meantime, I found a JavaScript solution in the Mozilla Developer Center's [article on Drag Operations](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DragDrop/Drag_Operations#dragfeedback). It may be of use to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't find any CSS property/value capable of disabling the drag preview -- neither standard nor Mozilla-specific. Sorry. :\

Comment: Thanks. I guess I can either just use JS or just live with it anyway!

Answer (score 1):

This is not specific to Firefox 4.  See this screenshot from my FF 3.6:

[image]